# Induced modules of for Virasoro, Witt algebras

Tags: modules, representation-theory, lie-algebras

**Background.** The Witt algebra is the Lie algebra with generators $\{l_n:n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ with bracket given by $$[l_m,l_n]=(m-n)l_{m+n}.$$ The Virasoro algebra is the unique central extension of the Witt algebra with the bracket relation given by $$[L_n,L_m]=(m-n)L_{m+n}+\frac{m^3-m}{12}\delta_{m,-n}K.$$

In http://library.msri.org/books/Book57/files/40mason.pdf, we define Vir$^\geq=\langle L_n,K: n\geq 0 \rangle$ and Vir$^-=\langle L_n: n<0\rangle$ and construct the 1-dimensional $\text{Vir}^\geq$-module $\mathbb{C}v_{c,h}$ by defining the actions $$K.v_{c,h}=cv_{c,h}$$ and $$L_n.v_{c,h}=\delta_{n,0} hv_{c,h}$$ for $n\geq 0$ ($v_{c,h}\neq 0$ and $c,h$ are arbitrary scalars). This gives rise to the induced (Verma) module $$M_{c,h}=\mathcal{U}(\text{Vir})\otimes_{\mathcal{U}(\text{Vir}^\geq)}\mathbb{C}v_{c,h}=\mathcal{U^-}(\text{Vir})\otimes \mathbb{C}v_{c,h}.$$ **Question.** Is there any obstruction to performing the analogous construction for the Witt algebra where the action of the central element no longer exists? I don't see why not, since the underlying vector space for the Witt algebra decomposes as $\text{Witt}^\geq \oplus \text{Witt}^-$ (assuming these have the obvious definitions analogous to above) and the module structure still makes sense without the action of $K$.

The reason I am interested in this is because I am trying to figure out what the obstacle is in constructing a vertex algebra from the Witt algebra ([Is it possible to construct a vertex algebra from the Witt algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4665884/is-it-possible-to-construct-a-vertex-algebra-from-the-witt-algebra)), since this would be a natural example of a VA if it existed but no sources mention it; I am assuming this is due to my misunderstanding of the above construction.

Comment: If A is an algebra, B a subalgebra of A, and M a B-module, you can always construct the induced A-module $A\otimes_BM$. This generalizes the construction of Verma modules by considering as A and B the enveloping algebras of the any Lie algebra and any of its subalgebras.